# Multiplying CASE row with different values

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating a rating system. I have two tables `hinne` (rating) and `hinnang` (rating multiplier). I need to multiply the rating and then average the rating to know what rating I got out of all ratings by `aine`(subject).

Example:

All points need to be calculated in 0-100 point system.

So if my first rate is 25 and the rating multiplier is 4 then first rate (25/25)

```
4*25=100
```

If the second rate is 30 and multiplier 2 then second rate (30/50)

```
2*30=60
```

Now I need to average them like `100+60/2=80`.

That should work in my SQL statement, but I got in trouble.

```
CASE
            WHEN aine.nimetus = 'Füüsika I'
            THEN hinne.tulemus * hindamine.kaal
            ELSE 0
          END
          ,0)
        ))
```

So, this is my pivot case statement. `hindamine.kaal` should be different value for each hinne.tulemus `25*4,50*2` BUT it doesn't work. It just uses multiplier value 4. How can I make this work?

- The result of SQL: 150
- The expected result: 100

Therefore here is my full SQL:

```
SELECT
   tudeng.m_number,hindamine.kaal, ROUND(AVG(NULLIF(
          CASE
            WHEN aine.nimetus = 'Füüsika I'
            THEN hinne.tulemus *  hindamine.kaal
            ELSE 0
          END
          ,0)
        ))
        AS FüüsikaI ,ROUND(AVG(NULLIF(
          CASE
            WHEN aine.nimetus = 'Kõrgem matemaatika I'
            THEN hinne.tulemus * hindamine.kaal
            ELSE 0
          END
          ,0)
        ))
        AS KõrgemmatemaatikaI ,ROUND(AVG(NULLIF(
          CASE
            WHEN aine.nimetus = 'Raalprojekteerimine'
            THEN hinne.tulemus * hindamine.kaal
            ELSE 0
          END
          ,0)
        ))
        AS Raalprojekteerimine ,ROUND(AVG(NULLIF(
          CASE
            WHEN aine.nimetus = 'Tehniline graafika'
            THEN hinne.tulemus * hindamine.kaal
            ELSE 0
          END
          ,0)
        ))
        AS Tehnilinegraafika , ROUND(AVG(NULLIF(
            CASE
              WHEN aine.nimetus = 'Ettevõteluse alused'
              THEN hinne.tulemus * hindamine.kaal
              ELSE 0
            END
            ,0)
            ))
          AS Ettevõtelusealused
FROM
 tudeng

INNER JOIN
 aine_tudeng
ON
 tudeng.tudeng_id =  aine_tudeng.tudeng_id

INNER JOIN
 aine
ON
  aine.aine_id = aine_tudeng.aine_id

INNER JOIN
 hinne
ON
 hinne.aine_tudeng_id=aine_tudeng.aine_tudeng_id

INNER JOIN
  hindamine
ON
  hindamine.hindamine_id=aine_tudeng.aine_id

GROUP BY
 tudeng.m_number
```

Comment: I'm using mysql server

Comment: I got lost after the first sentence :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your error is here:

```
ON hindamine.hindamine_id = aine_tudeng.aine_id
```

A **hindamine** (assessment/rating?) is something different from an **aine** (subject?), so you are mistaken in joining on these IDs.

(I have used Google translator to help me with the meanings.)